# Association of any kind inbetween QC projects?

Tags: hp-quality-center

I want to associate one QC project with another (e.g., manual testing and automation testing). I use QC 11.00

I would like to know what kind of association there can be between two QC projects (on the same domain), so I do not have to maintain two projects and then copy paste what I need e.g. common repositories etc.

Comment: You don't get answers since this is just a lookup in the dox.

Comment: hi blastone, what do you mean by dox?

Comment: Documentation of course

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do this. A project in QC is supposed to be a self-contained entity, that is, there is no way (that I know of) that you can automatically move data between projects.

Sure, you can copy and paste data, as well as create a project with another one as base, but that is probably not what you want.

I would rather have manual testing and automation in the same project, which makes more sense I think. The point is that the project is supposed to identify the **test object**, rather than the **test methodology** - the latter can be done better in Test Plan where you specify a Test Type when you create your test.

This way, you will have all defects and test reports for your test object in the same project which will make it all the easier to track what is going on.

Comment: i know koenig, that is exactly what i am doing, manual and auto in the same project. even then though, i need to have the auto tests in some other project and therefore keep it synchronized i.e i get the philosophy of QC. Anyway thanks for your answer as it is ensuring that synchro is out of the question. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule; you would want to keep all project data for one project in that project; and, you want project data from that project to be unique and separate from all other projects.

That being said... if you really wanted to do this (and were able to convince a QC subject matter expert that it was a good idea?), then it should be a relatively simple matter to amend the workflow with additional code to interface with another project.